# How can i find all iframe on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to know that is there any add-on available in firefox to find all iframe available on webpage.?

I want to use it for selenium webdriver automation to switch into iframe.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` ?

Comment: that i know that what is the command to get iframe. but i want to know that is there any firefox addon available which help to show all iframe on the webpage

Comment: Not exactly [an add-on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18889902/1169519), works in any browser, as long as all `iframe`s have the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Chrome

Use Chrome Developer debugging Tool to find all the available iFrames in the web page.

1. Open chrome web Browser
2. Press F12 key
3. Press Esc key
4. In console, you will see a filter icon followed by the dropdown `top frame`
5. Click on the dropdown to see the iFrames availability.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your valuable reply

finally i find answer of my problem.

Web Developer extension is addon for firefox. which have one option **"Outline Frames"** which highlight all iframes on the webpage

once we found iframes on the page we can get its name/ id / xpath/ css whatever we need in selenium automation using firebug.

thank you :)

[image]