# Get element value inside iframe which is nested inside Frame in javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame, getelementbyid

I main php page in which there are 2 frames. Inside the second frame there is iframe.
I want to access value of element on iframe document from the 1st frame.

I tried like this:

```
var frame1 = parent.frames[1];
var frame2 = frame1.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var eleValue =frame2.contentWindow.document.getElementById("MyElement").value;
```

but I am not receiving any value though it is there.

```
var frame1 = parent.frames[1];
alert(frame1.name);
var frame2 = frame1.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
alert(frame2.name);
var txtClinic = frame1.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementById("clinicFlag");
```

last line of code doesnot return any control object.

Comment: Are both the urls on same domain?

Comment: yes both urls are on domain

Comment: One hilarious way to pass information between frames is `window.LocalStorage()`

Comment: there is any other way to do it?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18889902/1169519)  should help you, it's not a perfect answer to your question though.

Comment: in my case iframe is nested inside the frame

Comment: I hope last line will give you some insight.

Comment: if you not prefer to use window.LocalStorage() then you can use cookies to pass the information across frames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a modified snippet of my answer linked in a comment. Function returns the `window` object of an (i)frame with `id` passed (`id`), or `null`, if the `(i)frame` is not found. This method works only, if all the `(i)frame`s are in the same domain. Also `id`s given to `(i)frame` elements must be unique throughout *all* documents involved in the window structure.

```
function searchFrame(id) {                                     // id = the id of the wanted (i)frame
    var result = null,                                         // Stores the result
        search = function (iframes) {                          // Recursively called function
            var n;                                             // General loop counter
            for (n = 0; n < iframes.length; n++) {             // Iterate through all passed windows in (i)frames
                if (iframes[n].frameElement.id === id) {       // Check the id of the (i)frame
                    result = iframes[n];                       // If found the wanted id, store the window to result
                }
                if (!result && iframes[n].frames.length > 0) { // Check if result not found and current window has (i)frames
                    search(iframes[n].frames);                 // Call search again, pass the windows in current window
                }
            }
        };
    search(window.top.frames);                                  // Start searching from the topmost window
    return result;                                              // Returns the wanted window if found, null otherwise
}
```

This function can find a `frame` or `iframe` with the passed `id` regardless where it is placed in the window structure. Also the function can be placed and called in any window. I'd put this to the main page (as global). If the method is needed in subwindows, just call with `top.searchFrame(...)`.

Instead of `id`s, also `name`s can be used, as long as they are also unique. In that case the `id` check in `searchFrame()` needs to be edited to `name` check.

In your case, first you need to give an `id` to the target `iframe`, then you can use the code for example like this:

```
var txtClinic = searchFrame('IFRAME_ID').document.getElementById('clinicFlag');
```

---

The method above might be a bit overkilling to get a single reference, but it's very helpful, if you have to get these cross-window references multiple times within different windows.

The specific task of yours could be done like this:

```
var txtClinic = parent.frames[1].frames[0].document.getElementById('clinicFlag');
```

---

`name`s of the `(i)frame` are also handy to use with `frames` collection. Instead indices you can use names. Just always chain the reference starting from the main page, i.e. from `top`. For example:

```
var iframeWin = top.frames['frame2'].frames['iframe1'];
```

---

Useful reading:

[window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top)
[window.frameElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frameElement)
[window.frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frames)

Comment: Hey @Teemu Is this code still relevant in 2022? I'm trying to apply it in order to detect an iframe buried in a page but it is not working. I get: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')```. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74215101/how-to-capture-iframe-after-all-page-elements-are-fully-loaded

Comment: Yes, the code still works as it is. Maybe you should ask a new question specifically about your use-case of this code.

Comment: Ah @Teemu I broke your first rule: ```Never write "It doesn't work" to the question, include an explanation of what goes wrong instead.```. Ok I will build a good question for this and will let you know if its ok.

Comment: Hey @Teemu I have posted a question about my issue. I hope my explanation is good enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74225479/how-to-capture-iframe-nested-within-shadow-doms-shadow-root-open-element