# window.myframeid.location.href is not working on google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, frameset

I have a page that uses an iframe. Underneath that there is a frameset which has two frames. One of the frame id is myframeid. Here is the code snippet.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe name="someiframe" src="/app/html/files">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <script>
function thismyfunction(dObj, dTo, dCode){
if (dTo == 'start'){
    if (tempora) {                  
        if (confirm('Is this correct?')){
            window.myframeid.location.href = '/code/cgi/bin';
        }
    } else {                                
        if (confirm('Prefer to view your account?')){
            window.myframeid.location.href = '/code/welcome/account';
}   }   
}
}
</script>
<frameset cols="30%, 70%" FRAMEBORDER=NO FRAMESPACING=0 BORDER=0>
<frame name="someframe" id="topframe" src="/app/source/default.htm" scrolling="no">
<frame name="someframe2" id="myframeid" src="/app/html/load">
  <input type="button" onclick="parent.thismyfunction(this.form, 'start')" 
     id="nicebutton"  value="Hello world" />
   </frameset>
  </body>
 </head>
</html>
</iframe>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

This is working on IE 11 but not working on google chrome version 36. Working as in when I click on the button using IE 11 browser, the function works. but not in google chrome. I think the google chrome doesn't like the below code.

```
 window.myframeid.location.href = '/code/cgi/bin';
```

Any ideas why? Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked, which object `window.myframeid` is in Chrome? Notice, that the `id` of the said frame is `"right"` rather than `"myframeid"`.

Comment: Good find @Teemu ! Thank you!! I edited the page. It was my mistake when posting the question.

Comment: I doubt that will fix your problem, it was just a conflict between the text and code in the question. `window.name` should refer to `window` object within a frame. Does it in Chrome?

Comment: Please put `console.log(window.myframeid)` before trying to set `href` of  its `location` object. Then open the console and refresh the page and click the button, what you see?

Comment: @Teemu It looks like the function can't reach myframeid. Isn't it?

Comment: Yep. Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24096958/1169519). It's not a direct answer to your question, but it contains a lot of useful information and links how to refer `(i)frames`.

Comment: @Teemu I looked at that answer. Very informative. Thanks! But I still have no luck. Its funny how it works in IE but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`myframeid` is an id, you can get a reference with `document.getElementById('myframeid')`.  You can load a new page by setting its `src` attribute.

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt I know where you are going with this. I tried this too but it did not help.

Comment: @Teemu this what I tried, so far.
I replaced,
window.myframeid.location.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
by the following line;
       document.getElementById("myframeid").location = 'http://www.yahoo.com';

Comment: It did not help. I got this error,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'location' of null

Comment: Use src instead of location.href.