# jQuery - how do I select parents of iframe from an element inside the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an element inside an iframe, such as the body of the iframe, and from this element I need to access all the parents of the specific iframe which this element belongs to. There may be more than one iframe in the document and I need only the parents of the specific iframe, filtered by a selector (such as class name).

If the element would not have been inside an iframe, I could do just `element.parents('.class-name');`. I need to check if this parent contains a specific descendant (filtered by a selector such as class name).

If the given element is not inside an iframe, just return its parents without any error message.

Comment: if you do a $("xxx").closest("yyy") inside an iframe it should only find you the "yyy" inside the iframe, it won't check the parent window.

Comment: because it's a frame you will have to get the `window.parent` which will be main page window and work from there to locate the iframe element

Comment: [Some info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24096958/1169519) about how to access `(i)frame`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I'm not sure if it's ideal but here it is:

```
var $element = jQuery(element);
var element_frame_element = $element[0].ownerDocument.defaultView.frameElement;
var element_parent = ((element_frame_element === null) ? $element : jQuery(element_frame_element)).parents('.class-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: `window.parent.$('.className')`