# Finding the image count in a web page

Tags: javascript, image

I have a JS code, that gets called in different web pages of my clients. I want to fetch the total number of images. **I want only those images that are visible to the user and not just any other images.** This is my JS code

```
    function getImageCount(topWindow) {
        try {
            var images = topWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('img');
            var imageCount;
            for (var i=0, length = images.length; i < length; i++) {
                var image = images[i];
                var clientWidth = image.clientWidth;
                if(clientWidth && clientWidth > 1) {
                    var src = image.getAttribute('src');
                    if(src) {
                        src = src.toLowerCase();
                        if(src.indexOf('.jpg') !== -1 ||
                           src.indexOf('.jpeg') !== -1 ||
                           src.indexOf('.gif') !== -1 ||
                           src.indexOf('png') !== -1) {
                           imageCount =  imageCount ? ++imageCount : 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return imageCount;
        } catch (e) {
            processError("getImageCount", e);
        }
    }
 var imageCount = getImageCount(top);
```

I have been trying a lot to stabilize this code so that it works correctly across all different types of web pages. Basically what I want is a generic code that captures image counts correctly.

Eg:
My code gives image count as 1 for http://www.msn.com/en-us/news/other/one-free-agent-every-nfl-team-should-sign-this-offseason/ss-AAmLlC0#image

What I want is a GENERIC CODE that gives me a correct image count irrespective of where it runs. Can some one give me some detailed solutions.

I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: should it count images in iframes also?

Comment: [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) at MDN. There are also images attached to the background of elements by CSS, and images drawn into canvas and svg elements, should they be taken into count too?

Comment: Yes, if they are visible, we need to take them into account.

Comment: I think you would have to count all css loaded images, as you can't know which are visible and which are not. And then you would need some function to check for images inside the viewport. But presumably you would need to bind that to a scroll function (as the images that are visible would change on scroll).

Comment: All the requirements you have makes the question too broad. There are posts about detecting element's visibility, and finding CSS-images, at SO, search for them. You can apply [the answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24096958) to search elements from iframes, "irrespective where [the code] runs". You could consider all canvases and svgs as images, technically they are, though they might contain plain text only. Combine all the details to your code, and if you'll get stuck, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

#### To simplt count all the images (`<img>`) on the page:

```
document.images.length
```

#### And to count all the "visible" images (ones with width and height):

```
[...document.images].filter(img => img.clientWidth && img.clientHeight).length
```

This will give you the number of images on the page. This does **not** include CSS images. since your code didn't either then I take it you want `<img>` ones

---

I didn't quite understand the meaning of *irrespective of where it runs*.. can you elaborate?

Comment: Top is basically a 'top' variable of javascript. I want the valid images that are  visible to the user and ignore all other images.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want only those images that are visible to the user. I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: @Juvenik - potentially visible? because the user might never scroll to see them or maybe they are *lazyloaded* so they are invisible until scrolled to. you cannot really know if they are *lazyloaded* or not.

Comment: what if they are not lazy loaded. How can get it.

Comment: @Juvenik - updated my answer to give count of all "visible" images (in ES6)

Comment: I want the CSS images too. If u see properly, my code is same as that of urs. But I want to change my code and make it generic to access all kinds of images that are visible to the user.

Comment: @Juvenik - you cannot know if images in the CSS are meant to be seen or not. some might be for `hover` purposed or for reloading and many times the CSS is referencing HTML code which doesn't exist at all or is deprecated. there is no point in checking the CSS *IMHO*.

Answer (score 0):

// Extract images

```
websiteImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
for (url in websiteImages) 
console.log(websiteImages.length);
```

//Extract inbound and outbound links

```
Links = document.querySelectorAll('a'); 
for (link in Links) 
console.log(Links[link].href);
```

1. Paste this Scripts into your console of browser
2. Check on the Below Link/ any Link you like
   (https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en)
3. The above-mentioned script will give all the Images present in the webpages.
   And the second script will give all the number of Inbound and Outbound/exit links
4. Just apply Some filter as per your use case and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of images on a webpage use the below code:

```
$$('img').length
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this simple approach for links**

$$('a').length