# Get Elements inside iframe which is nested inside Frame in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

**Edit:I'have solved the problem. You can check my comment below.**

I want to get html elements of all iframes.
These iframes can be located in my main page or they can be nested iframes.
I want to get all iframes elements.
There are many example on the internet to get elements of a specific iframe by id.
For example;
[Get element value inside iframe which is nested inside Frame in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074694/get-element-value-inside-iframe-which-is-nested-inside-frame-in-javascript)

But i dont want to specify main iframe id or anything like this. I want to reach all iframes.(nested or not nested)
I am very pleased if you can help me.
Thank you.

I also have an example but it can reach only top iframe on the page with specific id. 
Here is my example;

```
var htmlDocument = document_root;
var numberOfFrame = $("iframe[id^='" + rules.frameId + "']").length;
if (numberOfFrame > 0) {
    htmlDocument = $("iframe[id^='" + rules.frameId + "']")[numberOfFrame - 1].contentDocument;
    formName = $("iframe[id^='" + rules.frameId + "']")[numberOfFrame - 1].id;
    var iframeList = [];
    iframeHTMLObjectList.push(htmlDocument);
    for (i = 0; i < htmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length; i++) {
        iframeList.push(htmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < iframeList.length; i++) {
        iframeHTMLObjectList.push(iframeList[i].contentWindow.document);
    }
    console.log(formName);
}
```

Comment: Unless all these iframes are from same origin as main page you can't access them

Comment: For example; my main page has 2 iframes. These 2 iframes also have 3 iframes.So i want to get html elements of these 8 iframes.(2 main, 6 nested). Is there any way to access them? I guess it must be.

Comment: If they are on same domain need to let each frame page load then access internal frames. If not same domain can't access them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem with recursive method.
Here is my method:

```
function getIframeElements(htmlDocument) {
var frames = htmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
if (frames.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        try {
            formName = frames[i].id;
            getIframeElements(frames[i].contentWindow.document);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

    }
}

if (!iFrameArr.includes(htmlDocument)) {
    iFrameArr.push(htmlDocument);
}

return iFrameArr;
```

}