# How to capture iframe after all page elements are fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am trying to inject an HTML element into an iframe in a page not under my control, after a button inside this iframe is clicked. To do this I use a Chrome Extension. The code is in a content script of the extension. The content of the iframe is in the same domain as the body/main document.

I am not able to get the iframe from the page using variations of `getElement(s)By...` .
The page has 2 iframes, the main one is at the top of the DOM structure. I can see it perfectly when inspecting the elements. I need to get the "click" event from a button inside this iframe. But that iframe is returning as `null` if I try `getElementById`, and `undefined` if I try with `getElementsByTagName`. I tried to wait for the full load of the page with `setTimeout(`, `window.onload = function () {`, `window.addEventListener('load', function () {` combinations of this etc. My last attempt was this:

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        checkIframeLoaded();
    }else{
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        });
    }
  }

function checkIframeLoaded() {
    if(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
        let iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
        console.log(iframe); 
        iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("dd7975c81b0fac90f6bba640604bcb96").addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert("HURRAY!");
        });
    };
}
```

No matter what I do I cannot get the iframe detected. What am I doing wrong?

**E D I T :**
I suspect that the fact that iframe is buried within other "exotic" tags might make this iframe not detectable by normal means. I can see parent tags which are by order from parent to child:

`<body...>` 
`<macroponent-f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010...>` 
`#shadow-root (open)` 
`<div...>` 
`<sn-canvas-appshell-root...>` 
`<sn-canvas-appshell-layout...>` 
`<sn-polaris-layout...>` 
`<iframe...>` <-- I need to listen to click of a button inside an iframe, but the iframe is not detected.
`<button...>`

Some of these tags might be working as if they were another iframe? Meaning that I should try to get the iframe I want as if it was within another iframe? Or are these tags something else and the solution is different?
Also from seeing other questions it seems `#shadow-root (open)` might be an issue here.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-with-jquery?rq=1

Comment: I think you should repeat the `DOMContentLoaded` part for the `<iframe>`. And to be sure check its https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState too (if it's `complete`, you are past the `DOMContentLoaded` event, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: A low-budget workaround for testing purposes is to forget all loading events, and try accessing your stuff after a simple (say) 5-second delay. If it works that time, you'll know what you want to do can work, and only then dive into event chains and stuff.

Comment: @tevemadar Perhaps you'd like to have a look at this new question I posted. It's much more clear and with new information about the page and the obstacle I'm facing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74225479/how-to-capture-iframe-nested-within-shadow-doms-shadow-root-open-element